# Binary Vectorization Encoding for categorical variable grouped by date issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, one-hot-encoding

I'm having an issue trying to vectorize this in some kind of binary encoding but aggregated when there is more than one row (as the variations of the categorical variable are non-exclusive), yet avoiding merging it with other dates. (python and pandas)

Let's say this is the data

| id1 | id2 | type | month.measure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 105 | 50 | growing | 04-2020 |
| 105 | 50 | advancing | 04-2020 |
| 44 | 29 | advancing | 04-2020 |
| 105 | 50 | retreating | 05-2020 |
| 105 | 50 | shrinking | 05-2020 |

It would have to end like this

| id1 | id2 | growing | shrinking | advancing | retreating | month.measure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 105 | 50 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 04-2020 |
| 44 | 29 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 04-2020 |
| 105 | 50 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 05-2020 |

I've been trying with transformations of all kinds, lambda functions, pandas `get_dummies` and trying to aggregate them grouped by the 2 ids and the date but I couldn't find a way.

Hope we can sort it out! Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses pandas `get_dummies` to one-hot encode the "TYPE" column, then concatenates the one-hot encoded dataframe back with the original, followed by a groupby applied to the ID columns and "MONTH":

```
# Set up the dataframe
ID1 = [105,105,44,105,105]
ID2 = [50,50,29,50,50]
TYPE = ['growing','advancing','advancing','retreating','shrinking']
MONTH = ['04-2020','04-2020','04-2020','05-2020','05-2020']

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':ID1,'ID2':ID2, 'TYPE':TYPE, 'MONTH.MEASURE':MONTH})

# Apply get_dummies and groupby operations
df = pd.concat([df.drop('TYPE',axis=1),pd.get_dummies(df['TYPE'])],axis=1)\
       .groupby(['ID1','ID2','MONTH.MEASURE']).sum().reset_index()

# These bits are just cosmetic to get the output to look more like your required output
df.columns = [c.upper() for c in df.columns]

col_order = ['GROWING','SHRINKING','ADVANCING','RETREATING','MONTH.MEASURE']

df[['ID1','ID2']+col_order]

#    ID1  ID2  GROWING  SHRINKING  ADVANCING  RETREATING MONTH.MEASURE
# 0   44   29        0          0          1           0       04-2020
# 1  105   50        1          0          1           0       04-2020
# 2  105   50        0          1          0           1       05-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab([df['id1'],df['id2'],df['month.measure']], df['type']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
type  id1  id2 month.measure  advancing  growing  retreating  shrinking
0      44   29       04-2020          1        0           0          0
1     105   50       04-2020          1        1           0          0
2     105   50       05-2020          0        0           1          1
```